# How to use LINQ to convert a xml file in to an object

Tags: linq, linq-to-xml

I have xml files with following to generate the menu for our web site.

```
 <xs:element name="Menu">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="MenuItem" type="MenuItemType" maxOccurs="unbounded"></xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
        <xs:attribute name="Title" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
        <xs:attribute name="Type" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    </xs:complexType>

</xs:element>
<xs:complexType name="MenuItemType">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="MenuItem" type="MenuItemType" />
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="Text" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="Url" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

Right now I am using xmlserializer to convert these xml files in to Menu objects and use them to generate the menu. I want to use LINQ to xml to convert these xml files in to same object. Any help will be appreciated. Generated class for above xml file is

```
 public partial class Menu {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MenuItem")]
    public MenuItemType[] MenuItem;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Title;
    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Type;
}
public partial class MenuItemType {

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("MenuItem")]
    public MenuItemType[] Items;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Text;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
    public string Url;
}
```

Comment: This would be easier if we could see the actual XML for a menu as opposed to the schema definition for same.

Comment: why would you want to use Linq-to-XML instead of deserializing them directly? Deserializing an XML into an object seems like the much easier and preferable way to do this....

Comment: that is what I am doing right now. I am just interested to know how to convert an recursive xml in to object collection using LINQ.

Comment: @Murph, I have given schema because it represent the complete structure. Sample xml may not cover complete schema if schema contains any optional elements or attributes and we will not know how many child elements an elements contains.

Comment: @raj - fair point however you're still asking us to work with one hand tied behind our back, you've *got* examples and some of us at least would have to create them from scratch to work toward the desired result.

Answer (score 5):

I haven't tested it. But, hope this works.

```
var o = (from e in XDocument.Load("").Elements("MenuItem")
         select new Menu
         {
             MenuItem = GenerateMenuItemType(e).ToArray(),
             Title = (string)e.Attribute("Title"),
             Type = (string)e.Attribute("Type")
         });
```

---

```
private IEnumerable<MenuItemType> GenerateMenuItemType(XElement element)
{
    return (from e in element.Elements("MenuItem")
            select new MenuItemType
            {
                Items = GenerateMenuItemType(e).ToArray(),
                Text = (string)e.Attribute("Title"),
                Url = (string)e.Attribute("Url")
            });
}
```

Comment: Mehdi, thanks a lot. It would be great if we can find a solution that can do in single query.

Comment: The problem is your Xml document structure.the first-children have a different structure with their child. if you can change the Xml document structure and make a new permanent schema for all of the menu items, it's so easy to write it in a query.